# Static fields in inner classes

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

If I have class structure like that

```
public class Foo{
    //declaring fields and methods


    Foo(int k){
        Bar.a = k;
    }
    public class Bar{
        public final static int a;
    }
}
```

And if i create many instances of Foo, how does static field in class Bar acts? I mean, it is the same instance for all Foo objects or for each instance there is different static field?

Comment: No, all of the instances share the same static field, there won't be static field for every instances.

Comment: Your code wont compile. Non static nested classes can't contain static fields.

Comment: Actually, they can if the field is also final (which would make it a constant), but i'm just being picky :)

Comment: Updated question adding final modifier. How is it now?

Comment: LearnedfromMistake and Pshemo are correct, you cannot have a _modifiable_ (non-final) static field on a non-static inner class. Your code still won't compile since you are: 1) Not initializing the (now final) field `a`, 2) Trying to assign a new value to a final field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that Inner class cannot have static members as it requires an instance of Outer Class.

Answer (score 1):

The code will not compile, the compiler will emit

```
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
... error: Illegal static declaration in inner class blah.Foo.Bar
1 error
```

You need to have a `static` inner class in order for this code to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not correct. Just it makes no sense of asking about something that doesn't exist. The only possibility in that situation is to make inner class `static`. Then for each instance of outer class you have one static instance of inner class. And as a result one static variable of this inner class.